# improve find performance

Tags: bash, find

I have a bash script that zips up filenames based on user input. It is working fine albeit slowly since I have, at times, to parse up to 50K files.

```
find "$DIR" -name "$USERINPUT" -print | /usr/bin/zip -1 SearchResult -@
```

The @ sign here means that zip will be accepting file names from STDIN. Is there a way to make it go faster?

I am thinking of creating a cron job to update the locate database every night but I am not root so I don't even if it is worth it.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: First my to cents: `type -d` will make `find` only look for folder, so in principle it should make some difference. Could it be that `zip` is the bottleneck here? I would do a test using `tar czf` insted to compress the files and see if the performance is better.

Comment: Very possible that `zip` is the problem: I chose it because the users on the data are strictly window users. I don't know if GZIP or TAR can create anything readable on MS windows though. Any input welcome.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is your bottleneck. You really should profile the two steps first, by generating the file list separately from the zipping, putting it in a temporary file instead of piping. Then just call `date` before and after each step.

Comment: Try using -0 as argument instead of -1 just to see the difference. -0 means no compression at all, and thereby you should minimize the impact of CPU load/bottleneck. And as @mvds suggested, separate the jobs into two parts to see how long the find takes, and how long the zip takes.

Comment: Given the small amt of data going into the zip file, zip shouldn't be the bottle neck. zip will be waiting for disk accesses on the find search. Per an answer below, run multiple finds on separate sub-dir structures paths as available CPUs allow.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make use of parallel processing in xargs command to speed up your entire process. Use a command like this:

```
find "$DIR" -name "$USERINPUT" -print0 | xargs -0 -P10 zip -1 SearchResult -@
```

Above command will make xargs run 10 parallel sub-processes.

Please record timing of above command like this:

```
time find "$DIR" -name "$USERINPUT" -print0 | xargs -0 -P10 zip -1 SearchResult -@
```

and see if this makes any performance improvements.

Comment: Wow, great idea. I will take a stab at it and update this thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Mattias Ahnberg pointed out, this use of `find` will generate the entire list of matching files before `zip` gets invoked. If you're doing this over 50,000 files, that will take some time. Perhaps a more suitable approach would be to use `find`'s `-exec <cmd> {} \;` feature:

```
find "$DIR" -name "$USERINPUT" -exec /usr/bin/zip -1 {} \;
```

This way, find invokes zip itself on each matching file. You should achieve the same end result as your original version, but if the sheer number of files is your bottleneck (which, if the files are all small, is most likely), this will kick off running zip as soon as it starts finding matches, rather than when all matches have been found.

NB: I recommend reading the man page for find for details of this option. Note that the semi-colon must be escaped to prevent your shell interpreting it rather than passing it to find.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trawling through the filesystem running a find for each of the 50,000 files.

Why not do **one** run of find, to log names of all files in the filesystem, and then pluck the locations of them straight from this log file ?

Alternatively, break the work down into seperate jobs, particularly if you have multiple filesystems and multiple CPUs.  No need to be single-threaded in your approach.

Comment: His find-oneliner generates all the matching filenames in one chunk, and doesn't invoke zip on a file-by-file basis. He pipes this list into zip with the -@ argument (take list of files from STDIN) and also utilizes the -1 for minimal compression (although there is a -0 for NO compression to possibly try)).